# How to run a command a command as root on startup (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-12.04, root

I'd like to run a bunch of commands automatically on boot with root on Ubuntu 12.04 (for instance a `mount`)

I tried to put them in `/etc/rc.local` but didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Which commands are you trying to execute with `rc.local` ?

Comment: I have two commands a remote `mount` using NFS and a command that will send messages to a remote server. I'm working with HT-Condor so the command is `condor_master`. I don't know if the type of the command is important for being able to run it at startup.

Answer (score 1):

mounts should be defined in `/etc/fstab` instead.

Other than that, `/etc/rc.local` should work unless what you entered there is invalid for some reason. You need to ensure that it exits with a status 0, in addition having its executable bit set. If I'm not mistaken, it should have a permission mask of 755.

Based on your comment, it sounds like you're trying to launch stuff from rc.local, which is generally discouraged. I recommend writing start/stop scripts for them instead.

Comment: OK and how shoud I write such scripts

Comment: I couldn’t figure out how to add my NFS mount to `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @dev93 Here's how my secondary drive is mounted via fstab on my machine: `/dev/sda2 /media/jarmund/FesksloRPM ntfs defaults 0 0`
Adjust the device node and mount point, and you should be good.

Comment: I get en an error while booting. I think it's because I'm trying to `mount` a remote file system with NFS and the network is only available after the boot sequence